# PANDAS - How to get elapased days after group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and pandas. **I am having difficulties comming up with a column with the elapsed days since the occurence of the first case by country.** Similiar to the date column, but instead of a date I want the days since de first case (since the first occurence of a case/death/recovered within a country)

I have grouped the data by the country and date and summed confirmed, deaths and recovered cases. (Because the original data had some countries split withing regions) I also erased the days where there were no deaths, recovered or deaths (I want to count since the first case appeared).

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

```
covid_data = covid_data.groupby(['Country/Region', 'Date'])[['Confirmed', 'Deaths', 'Recovered']].apply(sum)
covid_data.sort_values(by=['Country/Region', 'Date'])
covid_data.reset_index()
covid_data = covid_data[(covid_data.T != 0).any()] #eliminates rows with no suspected, no deaths and no cured
```

Output:

```
Country/Region  Date       Confirmed    Deaths  Recovered
Afghanistan     2020-02-24  1            0       0
                2020-02-25  1            0       0
                2020-02-26  1            0       0
                2020-02-27  1            0       0
                2020-02-28  1            0       0
                2020-02-29  1            0       0
                2020-03-01  1            0       0
                2020-03-02  1            0       0
                2020-03-03  1            0       0
                2020-03-04  1            0       0
(and many other countries)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from some corrections to your "initial" code:

1. After `groupby` you have already your data sorted, so
   `covid_data.sort_values(by=['Country/Region', 'Date'])` is not needed.
   Actually this instruction doesn't change anything, as you didn't pass
   *inplace=True* parameter.
2. Now, when *Date* is in the index, it is time to eliminate rows with all zeroes
   in other columns, so run `covid_data = covid_data[(covid_data.T != 0).any()]`
   before you reset the index.
3. `covid_data.reset_index()` only generates a DataFrame with reset index,
   but also doesn't save it anywhere. You should correct it to:

   ```
   covid_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
   ```

And now let's get down to the main task.

Assume that the source data, after the above initial operations, contains:

```
  Country/Region       Date  Confirmed  Deaths  Recovered
0           Aaaa 2020-02-24          2       1          0
1           Aaaa 2020-02-25          2       0          0
2           Aaaa 2020-02-26          1       0          0
3           Aaaa 2020-02-27          3       0          0
4           Aaaa 2020-02-28          4       0          0
5           Bbbb 2020-02-20          5       1          0
6           Bbbb 2020-02-21          7       0          0
7           Bbbb 2020-02-23          9       1          0
8           Bbbb 2020-02-24          4       0          0
9           Bbbb 2020-02-25          8       1          0
```

i.e. 2 countries/regions.

To compute *Elapsed* column for each contry / region, define the following function:

```
def getElapsed(grp):
    startDate = grp.iloc[0]
    return ((grp - startDate) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
```

Then run:

```
covid_data['Elapsed'] = covid_data.groupby('Country/Region').Date.transform(getElapsed)
```

The result is:

```
  Country/Region       Date  Confirmed  Deaths  Recovered  Elapsed
0           Aaaa 2020-02-24          2       1          0        0
1           Aaaa 2020-02-25          2       0          0        1
2           Aaaa 2020-02-26          1       0          0        2
3           Aaaa 2020-02-27          3       0          0        3
4           Aaaa 2020-02-28          4       0          0        4
5           Bbbb 2020-02-20          5       1          0        0
6           Bbbb 2020-02-21          7       0          0        1
7           Bbbb 2020-02-23          9       1          0        3
8           Bbbb 2020-02-24          4       0          0        4
9           Bbbb 2020-02-25          8       1          0        5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I have a few questions: I should run the instructon to delete the rows with all zeros before reset the index because we only want to check the deaths, recovered and eleapsed columns? The getElapsed function receives as an argument the value of the Date column of everyrow right? iloc will select the first value of a group (so the start date)?

Comment: Yes (for all your questions).

Comment: One last question: Is there any advantage using your way of calculating the elapsed days (rather what I came up with)? Thank you for all your patience!

Comment: Where is your solution to compute "Elapsed" column? Your code sample contains only "initial" operations.

Comment: Sorry, the answer I came up with a few hours later: the other answer for this question.

Comment: Both solutions are OK.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem:

```
#aggregates de countries by date
covid_data = covid_data.groupby(['Country/Region', 'Date'])[['Confirmed', 'Deaths', 'Recovered']].apply(sum)

#sorts the countries by name and then by date
covid_data.sort_values(by=['Country/Region', 'Date'])

#eliminates rows with no suspected, no deaths and no cured
covid_data = covid_data[(covid_data.T != 0).any()] 

#get group by columns back
covid_data = covid_data.reset_index() 

#substructs the mim date from the current date (and returns the result in days - dt.days)
covid_data['Ellapsed Days'] = (covid_data['Date'] - covid_data.groupby('Country/Region')['Date'].transform('min')).dt.days
```

**EDIT**: With the contribution of [Valdi_Bo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7388477/valdi-bo)

```
#aggregates de countries by date
covid_data = covid_data.groupby(['Country/Region', 'Date'])[['Confirmed', 'Deaths', 'Recovered']].apply(sum)

#eliminates rows with no suspected, no deaths and no cured
covid_data = covid_data[(covid_data.T != 0).any()] 

#get group by columns back
covid_data.reset_index(inplace=True) 

#substructs the mim date from the current date (and returns the result in days - dt.days)
covid_data['Ellapsed Days'] = (covid_data['Date'] - covid_data.groupby('Country/Region')['Date'].transform('min')).dt.days
```